# How can a program use more memory than there is in the system?

Tags: memory

Earlier today, I was doing some 3D modeling in Blender when I noticed in the status bar that it was using over 34,000 MB of memory.

I checked my system stats, and to my surprise, it was indeed using 35 gigs of RAM without slowing down my OS at all.

[image]

[image]

The numbers don't add up. **5.58 GB of swap is used,** which obviously isn't enough to fit Blender.

How does this work? My computer has only 8 GB of RAM, and **I don't even have an extra 35 GB free** on my hard drive.

Comment: *it was indeed using 35 gigs of RAM* No. It is virtual memory size. The most part of it is cached into swap file(s) and is not present in physical memory. It will be restored from file to memory when needed (instead of some another memory blocks which will be stored into swap to free up some physical memory for this restoring). As in library - you can read one book, but you can put it back and take any another to read.

Comment: "Memory" and "RAM" are completely different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you are seeing here the effect of
Memory Compression, a feature that was introduced with OS X Mavericks.

The Apple article
[View memory usage in Activity Monitor on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/activity-monitor/actmntr1004/mac)
describes it as:

> - Memory Used: The amount of RAM being used. To the right, you can see where the memory is allocated.
>
>   - App Memory: The amount of memory being used by apps.
>   - Wired Memory: Memory required by the system to operate. This memory can’t be cached and must stay in RAM, so it’s not available to
>     other apps.
>   - Compressed: The amount of memory that has been compressed to make more RAM available.
>
>   When your computer approaches its maximum memory capacity, inactive
>   apps in memory are compressed, making more memory available to active
>   apps. Select the Compressed Memory column, then look in the VM
>   Compressed column for each app to see the amount of memory being
>   compressed for that app.

Applying this to your numbers, we see that Blender uses
35.40 GB memory in total. However, of this we find that 32.47 GB
are under Compressed Mem.
This leaves 35.4-32.47=2.93 GB of *uncompressed* memory for Blender.

This relates better to the number given of "App Memory: 2.54 GB",
which means that some of this uncompressed memory is swapped out.

The statistics don't say what is the memory footprint of the compressed
memory, but from the numbers we can conclude that the Blender data
is very highly compressible, perhaps because of many repeated bytes.

This conclusion is based on the total amount of real and swapped memory that
we see being used:

- App Memory: 2.54 GB
- Compressed: 1.29 GB

Total RAM used for applications is then 3.83 GB.

To this we add the swap used : 5.58 GB.

The applications then use all in all 9.41 GB of memory, where most
of it is swapped out. Blender seems as accounting for most of this.

The compression algorithm used by Apple and demonstrated here is
extremely impressive. We see an Apple computer with 8 GB RAM supporting a
35.40 GB application without a problem, as indicated by the
"Memory Pressure" graph being painted in green.

From
[Understanding Compressed Memory on the Mac](https://www.lifewire.com/understanding-compressed-memory-os-x-2260327):

> Compressed memory displays in the Memory Pressure graph, which indicates how actively the OS is involved in compressing RAM data. The graph turns from green (little pressure) to yellow (significant pressure), and finally to red, when there isn't enough RAM space, and memory has to be swapped out to the drive.

With a 35.40 GB application running, the Memory Pressure graph
indicates that there is only a "little pressure".
Very impressive compression factor indeed, a factor that I estimate
here to be around 3 (more or less).

Answer (score 2):

Besides compression and system-level swapping another technique might be relevant. If a file is mapped to memory it does not necessarily reside in memory completely. At least for the unchanged parts the system may utilize the original file as some kind of file-specific swap file instead. I do not know how this is implemented in MacOS, I just wanted to add this as possible part of the answer.